# Upgraded to 20.04 - Dash link icons not working?

Tags: desktop-icons

I use different shortcuts/icons for some very frequently used web applications (gmail, calendar, asana etc.) so that I could have them on the dash quick launcher and switch between them easily.

After upgrading to 20.04 (two days ago), something is broken with icons and all the applications launched via shortcuts are shown using the browser icon. Could anybody guide on what should be changed?

The desktop link file in /home/xxx/.local/share/applications/gmail.desktop (path also shown in screenshot 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Gmail
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --profile-directory=Default --app=https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0
Icon=/home/xxx/.local/share/icons/google_gmail.png
StartupWMClass=mail.google.com__mail_u_0
```

[image]

The icon file in /home/xxx/.local/share/icons/google_mail.png (path also shown in screenshot 2).
[image]

When I use the desktop launcher, the app is shown as expected (screenshot 3).
[image]

When the application is launched, the chrome icon is shown (screenshot 4) !!!
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: noone? This happens only to me?